# How many mob heads can I get from 1 Charged Creeper?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

If a Charged Creeper explodes and kills multiple mobs, do I get the chance for multiple mob heads? Or is it 1 Charged Creeper = 1 mob head?

I didn't find quantities on the Minecraft.wiki or tutorials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my testing, it seems that they drop 1 head no matter what. Even with many different types of mobs, you still get only 1 head. It seems to be the first mob that it kills that drop the head, others do not.

Comment: Unfortunatly, that's what i though. Needed a confirmation, even though i rather had another answer.